# How to update sub document field value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5396d07eccbc961622e55309"),
"userName" : "mulagala",
"groups" : [
    {
        "groupName" : "Default",
        "groupMembers" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "groupName" : "Family",
        "groupMembers" : [ ]
    }
  ],

}
```

I want to change the groupName `Family` to `Friends`.I have tried like the following

```
db.groups.update({ "userName" : 'mulagala' },{ "$rename": {"groups": {"groupName.Family" : 'groupName.Friends'}}})
```

I am getting this error

```
$rename target must be a string
```

Comment: According to doc (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename) is for used to change the **name** of a field, not its data!

Comment: @xlembouras, Yes thank you i got answer from Nill Lunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a field name but a "value" of a field. You update it with the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator and [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```js
db.groups.update(
    { "userName": "mulagala", "groups.groupName": "Family" },
    {
        "$set": { "groups.$.groupName": "Friends" }
    }
)
```

So you match the required element of the array and in the update part under [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) you specify the "position" with `$`. Then you just "set" the value to what you want.

Comment: added link for further reading -> http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/.